# How do I run a twisted trial in Windows?

Tags: python, installation, twisted, trial

I'm new to Python, [Twisted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_%28software%29), and Trial... and for Windows users the setup process isn't very clear.  Right now, I have Python 2.7 installed, along with Twisted.  From the Python GUI, I can run the reactor, so I'm convinced things are set up OK. But I can't figure out how to run trial from the command line to run my unit tests.  I don't see an executable anywhere for it.

[This post](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3878) gives me a hint that a patch needs to be installed in the twisted `setup.py`... Although I don't know where that file is located.  The comments mention I should just use the Twisted cmd shell, which again, I don't know where it is at.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing terribly special about running trial on Windows.  Run it like any Python script:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\trial.py [additional arguments]
```

Or if you have .py associated with a Python interpreter already:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\trial.py [additional arguments]
```

Or if you have the Python Scripts folder in your %PATH% already:

```
trial.py [additional arguments]
```

Or if you have that folder on your %PATH% and '.py' is in your %PATHEXT% already:

```
trial [additional arguments]
```